# Implementing MVC 5 IAuthenticationFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I don't understand the purpose/difference of OnAuthentication and OnAuthenticationChallenge aside from OnAuthentication running before an action executes and OnAuthenticationChallenge runs after an action executes but before the action result is processed.

It seems as though either one of them (OnAuthentication or OnAuthenticationChallenge) can do all that is needed for authentication. Why the need for 2 methods?

My understanding is OnAuthentication is where we put the logic of authenticating (or should this logic be in actual action method?), connecting to data store and checking for the user account. OnAuthenticationChallenge is where we redirect to login page if not authenticated. Is this correct? Why can't I just redirect on OnAuthentication and not implement OnAuthenticationChallenge. I know there is something I am missing; could someone explain it to me?

Also what is the best practice to store an authenticated user so that succeeding requests wouldn't have to connect to db to check again for user?

Please bear in mind that I am new to ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Those methods are really intended for different purposes:

- `IAuthenticationFilter.OnAuthentication` should be used for setting the principal, the principal being the object identifying the user.

You can also set a result in this method like an `HttpUnauthorisedResult` (which would save you from executing an additional authorization filter). While this is possible, I like the separation of concerns between the different filters.

- `IAuthenticationFilter.OnAuthenticationChallenge` is used to add a "challenge" to the result before it is returned to the user.
- This is always executed right before the result is returned to the user, which means it might be executed at different points of the pipeline on different requests. See the explanation of `ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction` below.
- Using this method for "authorization" purposes (like checking if a user is logged in or in a certain role) might be a bad idea since it might get executed AFTER the controller action code, so you might have changed something in the db before this gets executed!
- The idea is that this method can be used to *contribute* to the result, rather than perform critical authorization checks. For example you could use it to convert an `HttpUnauthorisedResult` into a redirect to different login pages based on some logic. Or you could hold some user changes, redirect him to another page where you can request additional confirmation/information and depending on the answer finally commit or discard those changes.
- IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization should still be used to perform authentication checks, like checking if the user is logged in or belongs to a certain role.

You can get a better idea if you check the source code for [`ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction`](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerActionInvoker.cs). The following will happen when executing an action:

1. `IAuthenticationFilter.OnAuthentication` is called for every authentication filter. If the principal is updated in the AuthenticationContext, then both `context.HttpContext.User` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` are updated.
2. If any authentication filter set a result, for example setting a 404 result, then `OnAuthenticationChallenge` is called for every authentication filter, which would allow changing the result before being returned. (You could for example convert it into a redirect to login). After the challenges, the result is returned without proceeding to step 3.
3. If none of the authentication filters set a result, then for every `IAuthorizationFilter` its `OnAuthorization` method is executed.
4. As in step 2, if any authorization filter set a result, for example setting a 404 result, then `OnAuthenticationChallenge` is called for every authentication filter. After the challenges, the result is returned without proceeding to step 3.
5. If none of the authorization filters set a result, then it will proceed to executing the action (Taking into account request validation and any action filter)
6. After action is executed and before the result is returned, `OnAuthenticationChallenge` is called for every authentication filter

I have copied the current code of `ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction` here as a reference, but you can use the link above to see the latest version:

```
public virtual bool InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName)
{
    if (controllerContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
    }

    Contract.Assert(controllerContext.RouteData != null);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(actionName) && !controllerContext.RouteData.HasDirectRouteMatch())
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "actionName");
    }

    ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor = GetControllerDescriptor(controllerContext);
    ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor = FindAction(controllerContext, controllerDescriptor, actionName);

    if (actionDescriptor != null)
    {
        FilterInfo filterInfo = GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);

        try
        {
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = InvokeAuthenticationFilters(controllerContext, filterInfo.AuthenticationFilters, actionDescriptor);

            if (authenticationContext.Result != null)
            {
                // An authentication filter signaled that we should short-circuit the request. Let all
                // authentication filters contribute to an action result (to combine authentication
                // challenges). Then, run this action result.
                AuthenticationChallengeContext challengeContext = InvokeAuthenticationFiltersChallenge(
                    controllerContext, filterInfo.AuthenticationFilters, actionDescriptor,
                    authenticationContext.Result);
                InvokeActionResult(controllerContext, challengeContext.Result ?? authenticationContext.Result);
            }
            else
            {
                AuthorizationContext authorizationContext = InvokeAuthorizationFilters(controllerContext, filterInfo.AuthorizationFilters, actionDescriptor);
                if (authorizationContext.Result != null)
                {
                    // An authorization filter signaled that we should short-circuit the request. Let all
                    // authentication filters contribute to an action result (to combine authentication
                    // challenges). Then, run this action result.
                    AuthenticationChallengeContext challengeContext = InvokeAuthenticationFiltersChallenge(
                        controllerContext, filterInfo.AuthenticationFilters, actionDescriptor,
                        authorizationContext.Result);
                    InvokeActionResult(controllerContext, challengeContext.Result ?? authorizationContext.Result);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (controllerContext.Controller.ValidateRequest)
                    {
                        ValidateRequest(controllerContext);
                    }

                    IDictionary<string, object> parameters = GetParameterValues(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);
                    ActionExecutedContext postActionContext = InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(controllerContext, filterInfo.ActionFilters, actionDescriptor, parameters);

                    // The action succeeded. Let all authentication filters contribute to an action result (to
                    // combine authentication challenges; some authentication filters need to do negotiation
                    // even on a successful result). Then, run this action result.
                    AuthenticationChallengeContext challengeContext = InvokeAuthenticationFiltersChallenge(
                        controllerContext, filterInfo.AuthenticationFilters, actionDescriptor,
                        postActionContext.Result);
                    InvokeActionResultWithFilters(controllerContext, filterInfo.ResultFilters,
                        challengeContext.Result ?? postActionContext.Result);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            // This type of exception occurs as a result of Response.Redirect(), but we special-case so that
            // the filters don't see this as an error.
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // something blew up, so execute the exception filters
            ExceptionContext exceptionContext = InvokeExceptionFilters(controllerContext, filterInfo.ExceptionFilters, ex);
            if (!exceptionContext.ExceptionHandled)
            {
                throw;
            }
            InvokeActionResult(controllerContext, exceptionContext.Result);
        }

        return true;
    }

    // notify controller that no method matched
    return false;
}
```

As for not hitting the db on every request when setting the principal, you could use some sort of server side caching.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, if I understood correctly, setting the principal is done on OnAuthentication. But should, this be where I check the data store for users? Also, in number 2 "If any authentication filter set a result, for example setting a 404 result, then OnAuthenticationChallenge is called for every authentication filter". What do you mean by this? When I add a breakpoint, it always runs OnAuthenticationChallenge whether I set a result or not (I even tried setting result to null).

Comment: Thinking, I can't seem still see why use OnAuthenticationChallenge. I am thinking something like OnAuthentication, authenticate user, if not authenticated, redirect to log in via the context result, else continue. This can all be done in OnAuthentication. Could you provide a practical example why/when I should use OnAuthenticationChallenge?

Comment: In OnAuthentication you may set the result to `HttpUnauthorisedResult`. Then on OnAuthenticationChallenge, you could override that result and return a `RedirectResult` to different pages based on some logic. Because this logic is in the OnAuthenticationChallenge, it would also be applied if the `HttpUnauthorisedResult` is returned directly from a controller action, from an authorization filter or from any other filter.

Comment: @DanielJ.G. That last sentence explained it well. Thanks.